# Is there a good (gitorious-like) server for mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

At the company where I work we are using hg as (d)vcs.
Most of the repositories in use are kept in a cenralized space and served via hgweb.

For ease of use and better user experiance (and overview) I like to have something like gitorious (github, bitbucket).
It should allow

- hg as backend (or else I'd install gitorious...)
- local installation (not per developer, but locally on our site / not hosted)
- easy (web-based) repository-creation
- personal forking (cloning, but keeping the new repo physically on the same server)
- merge requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm completely biased, since I'm a developer on it, but [Kiln](http://fogcreek.com/kiln) does a very good job helping you create and manage repositories. It also has code reviews and is commercially supported. You can install on your own server, or Fog Creek will host it for you.

Comment: Yes, I thought Kiln would be an option.. What kept me from trying si the price, though... ;-)

Comment: @Nils I confess to finding some irony with software shops unwilling to pay for software. :)

Comment: @Benjamin There is no "unwillingness" in general - just when the price gets more than 100 (rough..) and for such "low-profile" things as vcs.. (well it worked all the years without - why spend money now...) But I already hinted the irony more than once...

Comment: @Benjamin I've got a manager with a firm hand on the budget and the tools budget is already exhausted (may not be Nils' situtation, but it is the one I'm often in).  I'm not willing to wait a year, but I can get permission to implement a free solution.  If they'd authorize it, I'd pay, but they won't so I can't

Comment: Kiln does not appear to have a self hosting option any longer.

Comment: @JasonSouthwell True, that has been discontinued.

Answer (score 15):

A good tool is [RhodeCode](https://rhodecode.com) that serves Mercurial. It looks really good, has user management, grouping, LDAP integration hook control and some graphing options.

The current release (1.3.x) supports git repositories.

Comment: looks promising - much better than the hgweb we're using now. -- I'll give it a try in the next days...

Comment: in new 1.3 release it will rock with git and have code review.

Comment: I am also looking for pure python. If theres none i am planning on writing one (may be using tornado as web backend) would be fun :)

Answer (score 4):

You should make this decision looking at the [PublishingRepositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories) wiki page.

My preferred solution is to use the [hg-ssh](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SharedSSH?highlight=(hg-ssh)) script that already comes with your mercurial install.  It makes it very easy to give multiple people ssh access without creating a separate system account for each, and without giving them shell access.  It's very easily configured in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the single shared user.

Repository creation isn't web-based, but it's very easy and personal forking is completely supported:

```
hg clone ssh://shared@server/main/repo ssh://shared@server/my-personal/repo
```

I then set up the hgweb script that comes with mercurial to provide a read-only view, and rely on ssh:// for all writes (though hgweb also does writes / push just fine).

If you *really* think web based repo creation is easier than one-line ssh-based creation I've previously written a stupidly simple script to do so:

http://ry4an.org/unblog/UnBlog/2009-09-17

Someone is going to suggest "mercurial server", and I'd recommend against it.  It's not current and never added much value over ssh.

Comment: Yes, using ssh seems a good alternative, but in my workarea (Windows-only and "I don't use commandlines") maybe not applicable. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 2):

[BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org).

They are the official HG host, and are actually very good.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a server he can run himself, not an offsite service provider.

Comment: Exactly - I was looking for a server, not a service provider. (What I meant by "not hosted"...)

Comment: They actually have an Intranet solution now